# CakePHP Session Expires redirect to /users/login

Tags: session, cakephp, redirect

Been having a trouble with these redirect since I set my redirect to /admins/login this is my `AppContoller` on CakePHP.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
             'Form' => array(
                'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
                ),
                "userModel" => "Admin",
             )
        )
    ),
    'Session',
);

public $helpers = array(
    'Html', 
    'Form', 
    'Session'
);

public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = "events/admin_index";
    //$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'admin_index'); ibutang pa ni nako nga code
}

public function beforeRender() {

    $this->set("sessions", $this->Auth->user());
    $this->set("params", $this->params);

}

}
```

The redirect to /users/login is rare but still wanna know why it goes to that link. I would be glad if somebody can explain it to me.

PS: My project worked on is not mine it was handled to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the duration of your session in Config/core.php ? if it's set to `'php'` (default value), maybe your php.ini is short about session duration. Therefore, you can be redirected to /users/login because you session expired while you were trying to access to a restricted admin view, so Auth asks you to log in again.

You can use the [CakePHP session handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration) to choose how and how long sessions stay alive.

Comment: Thanks Meowcate I will look into it and try to see if it will happen or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the loginRedirect and logoutRedirect like this.

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I will try it that way Justin Atack and give you my feedback.